# How to programmatically change video codec in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, video, html5-video

I've recently run into a issue with taking video on new iPhones(8 and up) written in Xamarin. When capturing the video video on older devices the codec is H.264, but on new devices Apple has switch to H.265. These videos are played in browser and pretty much everything I've checked doesn't support H.265.

Since you can change in the setting of the device between (high efficiency-H.265 and most compatiable-H.264), I figured you can do this programmatically. I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this if at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the codec on a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, which you add to your Session, through `WeakVideoSettings` which is just a dictionary of settings.

You can find the keys in the official apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput/video_settings_dictionaries